# リターンキーを押すと新しい行にチェックボックスを生成する

Tags: swift

簡単なToDoリストを作ろうと思い、チェックボックスと、その横にあるTextfieldまでは作れました。
しかし、Textfieldで改行をしたら新しいチェックボックスが現れる（Evernoteのチェックボックス機能のようなものです）ようにしたいのですが、それができません。一体どうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/jchirs/items/ffdae6f78c8d9818d313

Comment: Delegate（デリゲート）はご存知ですか？ご存知であれば、`UITextField`のDelegateの話をしますし、ご存知でなければ、そもDelegateは何かという話をします。

Comment: @nagonsoftware ありがとうございます。自分で調べてはみたのですが、いまいちわかっていない状況です。delegateのお話からご説明いただけたら嬉しいです。

Comment: @nagonsoftware 大変わかりやすい説明ありがとうございました。おかげさまでとても助かりました。初心者なりに頑張っていこうと思います。

Comment: 各回答の下にもコメント欄があるので、回答に対するコメントにはそちらをお使いください。また質問が解決したら、回答左側にあるチェックマークをクリックする「承認」という操作を行っていただけると、質問が解決済みであることがわかりやすくなります。

Comment: @unarist ご指摘ありがとうございます。あまり使い方を分かっておらずご迷惑をおかけしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Delegateはなにかをお話しする前に、Delegateはなにに使われるか、どういう目的で使われるかという話をします。*

●イベント駆動型プログラム

iOSは、種々のイベントを引き金（トリガー）にして、処理を開始する、イベント駆動型をとっています。ユーザが画面をタップする、キーボードで入力する、デバイス本体を傾けるという、ユーザが起こすイベント。アプリが、他のアプリの裏側に回ったとか、表に出てきたという、状態の変化を示すイベント。GPSから、位置情報の変更をイベントとすることもありますし、ネットワーク経由で、サーバの応答をイベントとして受け取ることもあります。[（イベント駆動型プログラム）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E9%A7%86%E5%8B%95%E5%9E%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)
イベント発生から、処理を開始する仕組みは、いくつかの種類を、iOSは用意しています。
**Action-Targetパラダイム**
XcodeのStoryboardで、ボタンを、ソースコード上のメソッドにConnect（接続）する作業を、なさったことがあると思います。画面操作のユーザイベントを受け取る`UIControl`オブジェクトがあり、指定された対象（Target）が持つメソッド（Action）を呼ぶ仕組みを、Action-Targetパラダイムといいます。
`UITextField`は、`UIControl`のサブクラスであり、ユーザのイベントを受け取るようになっています。[Structure UIControlEvents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents)に、`UIControl`が受け取るイベントの種類が一覧になっていますが、`editingDidBegin`や`editingDidEnd`のように、`UITextField`専用のイベントもあります。
**Notification（通知）**
Action-Targetパラダイムは、基本1対1の関係でしたが、1対多でメソッドを呼び出す、Notificationというシステムがあります。詳しい説明はしませんが、使えるようになると、役立つシステムです。`UITextField`にも、[`UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1619616-uitextfieldtextdidbeginediting)、[`UITextFieldTextDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1619640-uitextfieldtextdidchange)、[`UITextFieldTextDidEndEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1619633-uitextfieldtextdidendediting)、3つのNotificationがあります。
ほかに、**Gesture Recognizer**がありますが割愛して、つぎにDelegateを取り上げます。

---

●Delegate（委譲）

ウィキペディアの[委譲](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A7%94%E8%AD%B2)にあるように、Delegateは、イベント駆動専用で使われる手法ではありませんが、iOSではイベント駆動で呼び出すメソッドとして、多用されます。XcodeでiOSのプロジェクトを作成すると、かならず`AppDelegate`クラスができますが、これは`UIApplication`のDelegateを集めたクラスになっています。
UIKitのリファレンス上では、Delegateはプロトコルにまとめられていますから、`UITextField`のDelegateは、[`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)で調べることができます。じっさいに調べてみると、`textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`というDelegateメソッドがあり、その名からテキストフィールド入力中に、リターンキーをタップした時に、呼ばれるメソッドではないかと想像されます。そして、そのとおり呼ばれます。

---

●Delegateメソッドの実装

Delegateメソッドの具体的な実装の仕方を説明します。
まず、委譲元にしたいオブジェクト（クラス）が、本当に委譲できるのか確認します。確認の仕方はかんたんで、クラスリファレンスを調べ、`delegate`プロパティがあれば、委譲ができます。`UITextField`クラスにも[`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619595-delegate)プロパティがあるので、委譲できます。
委譲先のオブジェクトを指定します。さきの`delegate`プロパティに、委譲先のオブジェクトを代入します。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self // View Controller自身を、委譲先とする。
    }

}
```

この記述は、Storyboard上の編集としても行えます。Text FieldからView Controllerに接続して、表示されたプルダウンメニューから選択します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

つぎに、委譲先オブジェクトに、Delegateメソッドを定義します。
クラス宣言に、プロトコル名`UITextFieldDelegate`を追加します。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

忘れやすいので、気をつけてください。
Delegateメソッドには、Required（必須）と、Optional（オプション）の2種類があり、Requiredは、その名のとおり、かならず実装しなければいけません。`UITextFieldDelegate`のメソッドは、すべてOptionalで、実装したいものだけ定義します。詳しくは、各Delegateプロトコルのリファレンスに書かれていますから、使用時、熟読することをお勧めします。

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("Return key was pressed.")
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

iOSシミュレータで実行してみて、Text Fieldにテキスト入力後、リターンキーを押して、上のメソッドが実行されることを、確認してください。ちなみに、`resignFirstResponder()`メソッドは、キーボードを非表示にする役目があります。そして、`textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`メソッドは、`Bool`型の返り値を持っていることに注意してください。`true`を返さないと、リターンキーのプレスがキャンセルになります。

---

●まとめ

1. Delegateは、イベント発生を受けて、メソッドを実行する手法として、使われることが多い。
2. Delegateメソッドは、プロトコルとしてまとめられている。
3. Delegateメソッドには、RequiredとOptionalがある。